# Jquery Mobile - search input has no value on post after AJAX loaded content

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am having an issue where when a page is loaded via Ajax, I don't have a value in my search input. Here is my HTML:

```
<form id="searchForm" action="javascript:;" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="search" name="search-mini" id="search-mini" value="" data-mini="true" />
        <input type="submit" data-mini="true" value="Search"  />
    </div>
</form>
```

The reason we have an input button is because of a request from the client as they found people having scenarios where they would click "Done" on the IOS keyboard rather than "Search" which wouldn't submit the form. here is my Javascript that handles the submit:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#searchForm', function () {
    var text = $("#search-mini").val();
    text = encodeURIComponent(text);
    window.location.href = "/Mobile/Browse/Text?text=" + text;
    return true;
});
```

This all runs fine if I refresh the page so the content is not loaded via AJAX. It only fails when linking between pages and they are loaded by AJAX. Alerting out "text" has a blank value in this scenario.

I have read about using JQM initialization events such as 'PageInit' instead of DOM ready() I just need an example implementing this with my code if this is the correct approach?

Regards,

Danny

Comment: Where exactly are you using AJAX? Your code you are showing doesn't contain any. Why are you using JS so submit the form? If you set the `action` to `/Mobile/Browse/Text` and `name` the search field `text` you'd get the exact same result.

Comment: AJAX is used to load the pages when linking between pages. This search is apart of my "Layout/Masterpage" as it appears in the header of every page. So when linking to another page with AJAX (default behavior/intention) it stops working unless the page is refreshed. The reason we are using java script is to encode special characters " / ? : @" etc

Comment: So I understand it correctly: After the line `var text = $("#search-mini").val();` the variable `text` contains an empty string? The only reason for that can be that something you are not showing is interfering. Can you put an example page online or use jsFiddle? You don't need to use JS to encode the string. That will happen automatically with a normal form submit.

Comment: Ok I tried to replicate this for you in a jsFiddle but it ended up becoming a bit of a task in itself. Based on your comment about the encode of the string. I have now changed it as per your first comment and this is working fine! Thanks for your contributions, saved some time and simplified the code/process! :)